# Auto-populate cell, based on another cell's value, without formulae

Tags: excel

I've seen a couple of spreadsheets over the years that had a blank, unpopulated, non-formula cell, that would populate when another cell was populated correctly. I am wondering if there is a way to do this without using add-ons, or VBA.

Scenario:

1. User is asked to enter a value in cell A1.
2. If the value is X, cell B1 populates with a value.
3. If the value is Y, cell B1 remains blank.

I know that this can be done with a formula such as `=IF(A1="","",IF(A1=1234,"Hello 1234",""))`.

However, I am wondering if it is possible to do this without a formula in cell B1, but still have cell B1 populated?

Comment: Without a formula or VBA? That is a real challenge for SOers...

Comment: Why do you want to do it without a formula or VBA?

Comment: Are you sure the cell you saw was actually blank? Or was it a formula masquerading  is a blank value (*like the formula you shared*)? Or, are you sure they did this without VBA? Maybe you made some false assumptions about what you saw and it was likely either one of the above options you asked us not to use. Even if the assumption was correct, can you explain how not using formulas or VBA makes this better? What is the value add to avoiding the obvious solution? :)

Comment: It sounds like a change event, but there would be at least one other way to do this, provided the value in B1 was static... with conditional formatting, you could make B1 default the same color as the background, and if a criteria is met in A1 then the format of B1 changes to a different font color.  This would mean that B1 has a value and its *visibility* is determined by conditional formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, it sounds like this might be what you witnessed. Macros can be set to trigger automatically given a certain event & criteria met. In this instance, the macro will fire when you make a `Worksheet_Change` in cell `A1`.

*Note that the change to A1 must be manual to fire macro - a change due to formula will not suffice to trigger macro*

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target = "X" Then
        Range("B1") = "X Result"
    ElseIf Target = "Y" Then
        Range("B1") = "Y Result"
    End If
End If

End Sub
```